# Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and now my monitor is shown as 'Uknown Display' and second monitor doesnt even show up

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I followed some basic instructions:

`ubuntu-drivers devices`
and
and `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the nvidia  `nvidia-driver-515` but my monitor, which is Benq XL2411, is shown as `Unknown Display` without beeing able to put `144 Hz`.

Can I somehow fix this super weird ubuntu-thing?

Comment: I think display driver is broken in the new 22.04. Ubuntu have to test the nvidia drivers before putting in their repo, as I tried their tested nvidia driver and I have the same issue. My external monitor is not recognized. I tried to use the X.Org the open source  driver, which beautifully recognizes the second monitor but it crashes my other applications like zoom client etc. So right now we need to wait for a patch or update to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried versions 390, 418, 450, 455, 460, 470, 510, 515, 525.
Unsuccessful.

Can't get more than 1600x900. Tried it on DVI-D. Didn't work.
If I try to use xrand do add full hd res, is returns error:

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  37
Current serial number in output stream:  38

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1282391)